# Saving file to AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've been following some examples here and on Google of how to write a Nodejs Lambda function to fetch an (audio) file from a URL and save it to S3.  I've arrived at this so far:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var https = require('https');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

const querystring = require('querystring');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  const params = querystring.parse(event.body);
  const audioUrl = params['audioUrl'];

  https.get(audioUrl, function(res) {
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      // Agregates chunks
      body += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      // Once you received all chunks, send to S3
      var params = {
        Bucket: 'bucket_name',
        Key: 'filename.wav',
        Body: body
      };
      s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.error("ERROR: ", err, err.stack);
        } else {
          console.log("DATA:", data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
```

This results in file with filename *filename.wav* being saved to S3 bucket but the file is not a WAV audio file which is what I want.  It seems that in the process of retrieving the file from audioUrl and saving it to S3 the format/encoding of the file is lost.

Any hints or solutions to this would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're converting a binary file, into a string, that's why your uploaded file is corrupted. What you need to do is work with `Buffer` instead of `string`.

```
const chunks = [];
res.on('data', function(chunk) {
   // Agregates chunks
   chunks.push(chunk)
});

res.on('end', function() {
  // Once you received all chunks, send to S3
  var params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket_name',
    Key: 'filename.wav',
    Body: Buffer.concat(chunks)
  };
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("ERROR: ", err, err.stack);
    } else {
      console.log("DATA:", data);
    }
  });
});
```

In any case, instead of buffering the chunks, is better to just pass the stream directly, and let the S3 SDK handle it.

```
var params = {
  Bucket: 'bucket_name',
  Key: 'filename.wav',
  Body: res // pass the readable stream directly
};

s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {});
```

The only caveat of passing a stream directly, is that the library can only work with streams that it can determine the length of. If that request sets the content-length correctly, you won't have any issue.

- [S3.putObject only accepts streams that it can determine the length of](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2961)
- [streaming images doesnt work](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/94)

You can bypass this limitation, by using `s3.upload` instead.

---

Note: Haven't worked with the S3 SDK in a while, but they didn't support pipe last time I used it, to do directly: `res.pipe(s3.putObject())`